# Wordpress returns a 404 when non-default permalinks are used

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a Wordpress installation and I would like to configure permalinks with the post name rather than the default ?p=xx syntax.

But I just get a 404 when accessing the posts, and I am not sure where it goes wrong.

I've tried the suggestions provided by Wordpress (setting the permissions of .htaccess to 660 and then re-saving the permalinks options in the WP backend), and even deleting the .htaccess file, but it successfully gets recreated.

I've looked at the phpinfo() output to verify that mod_rewrite is loaded.

What else could it be?

Comment: Please share some code or a link otherwise we cannot really help. There is a difference between `$_GET` and `$_POST` so you need to cater for this.

Comment: I've not as such written any code. I simply went to Wordpress -> Settings -> Permalinks and selected the "Post name" option. Here's the content of .htaccess:

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

And here's what I get when clicking "view" in any of the Posts: http://netwerk.dk/the-4sound-website-project/

The output of phpinfo includes "mod_rewrite" in the apche2handler / Loaded modules section.

Comment: It turned out not to be a Wordpress issue. My apache config file was set up with AllowOverride None. Changed it to AllowOverride All and restarted apache, and then it worked like a charm.